# Parameter undefined when calling a function on other file within a function

Tags: python

Here is my code which finds complex words from a word list.

"complex_words.py"

```
def complex_words_count(words_list):
    cw_count = 0
    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
    for word in words_list:
        syl_count = 0
        for w in vowels:
            if w in word and word[-2:len(word)] != 'es | ed':
                syl_count+=1
        if syl_count > 2:
            cw_count+=1
    return cw_count

from Words_Count import word_count

def complex_words_percent():
    cwc = complex_words_count(words_list)
    wc = word_count(words_list)

    percent_cw = int(cwc/wc*100)

    return percent_cw
```

"Words_Count.py"

```
def word_count(words_list):

    wc = len(words_list)

    return wc
```

"Test.py"

```
from complex_words import complex_words_count, complex_words_percent

a = ['inferno', 'shamed', 'changes', 'umbrella']

cw_c = complex_words_count(a)

cw_p = complex_words_percent()
```

The complex_words_count() function works absolutely fine, but the problem lies within the complex_words_percent()

[Here's a screenshot representing the fault in the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIZ4e.png)

Output on running "Test.py":

[Output of "Test.py"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xr3ok.png)

I'm not getting a way how to run the "Test.py" without any errors.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code or error messages. Just put the text directly in your question.

Comment: As for the actual problem, the error message tells you what's wrong. There is no variable called `words_list` in the `complex_words_percent` function. Where exactly are you expecting that variable to be initialized, and what value do you expect it to hold?

Comment: Actually, I'm new to python,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You passed the words list `a` to the `complex_words_count` function, but `complex_words_percent` knows nothing about it. You have to add it as a parameter to that function as well:

```
def complex_words_percent(words_list):
    cwc = complex_words_count(words_list)
    wc = word_count(words_list)

    percent_cw = int(cwc/wc*100)

    return percent_cw
```

and pass it when you call the function:

```
cw_p = complex_words_percent(a)
```

If you want to share values between functions then you should put them in a class:

```
class ComplexWords:
    def __init__(self, words_list):
        self.words_list = words_list

    def count(self):
        words_list = self.words_list
        ... rest of code here ...

    def percent(self):
        words_list = self.words_list
        ... rest of code here ...
```

Then you use it:

```
cw = ComplexWords(a)
cw_c = cw.count()
cw_p = cw.percent()
```

Comment: Your solution worked and gave the output as I desired,

Comment: But I wanted to add no parameter in complex_words_percent(), is there any way to let complex_words_percent recognize that it has to take "words_list" from the word_count and complex_words_count functions

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer @Duncan, actually now I got several ways to do a thing, Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Edit to "complex_words.py"

```
w0 = []
def complex_words_count(words_list):
    global w0
    w0 = words_list
    cw_count = 0
    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
    for word in words_list:
        syl_count = 0
        for w in vowels:    
            if w in word and word[-2:len(word)] != 'es | ed':
                syl_count+=1
        if syl_count > 2:
            cw_count+=1
    return cw_count

from Words_Count import word_count 

def complex_words_percent(words_list = None):
    if words_list is None:
        words_list = w0

    cwc = complex_words_count(w0)
    wc = word_count(w0)

    percent_cw = int(cwc/wc*100)

    return percent_cw
```

This gave me the exact output which I wanted from "Test.py"